# PHP Fail to delete record from table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete the record from the vaccinedetail table, i've tried to run the delete statement in phpmyadmin and it ran perfectly. But when i tried the delete statement in my code, it wont delete the record.Any idea??

```
<?php
include('connect-db.php');

if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM vaccinedetail WHERE id=$id") or die(mysql_error());
    header("Location: start.php");
}
else
{
    header("Location: displaytype.php");
}
?>
```

.

```
<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Vaccine ID</th>
        <th>疫苗名稱 (繁體)</th>
        <th>疫苗名称 (简体)</th>
        <th>Vaccine Name (Eng)</th>
        <th>Total no of injection</th>
        <th>Nth Injection</th>
        <th>Next Injection Skip</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

<?php
include('connect-db.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT vaccinedetail.id,vaccinedetail.vaccineid,vaccinedetail.vaccinename1,vaccinedetail.vaccinename2,vaccinedetail.vaccinename3, vaccinedetail.totalnoofinjection,vaccinedetail.nthinjection,vaccinedetail.skip FROM vaccinedetail WHERE vaccinedetail.vaccineid = '" . $_POST['vaccineid'] . "'") or die(mysql_error()); 
// ^^^ show the specifc type of vaccine taht match the vaccine type in the typeserach.php
?>

<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
?>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name = "id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"</td>
        <td><input type="text" name = "vaccineid[]" value="<?php echo $row['vaccineid'] ?>"</td>
        <td><input type="text" name = "vaccinename1[]" value="<?php echo $row['vaccinename1'] ?>"</td>
        <td><input type="text" name = "vaccinename2[]" value="<?php echo $row['vaccinename2'] ?>"</td>
        <td><input type="text" name = "vaccinename3[]" value="<?php echo $row['vaccinename3'] ?>"</td>
        <td><input type="text" name = "totalnoofinjection[]" value="<?php echo $row['totalnoofinjection'] ?>"</td>
        <td><input type="text" name = "nthinjection[]" value="<?php echo $row['nthinjection'] ?>"</td>
        <td><input type="text" name = "skip[]" value="<?php echo $row['skip'] ?>"</td>

        <!--<td><a href="editdisplaytype.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><img src="edit.png" width="20px"></a>-->
        <td><a href="deletedisplaytype.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><img src="delete.jpg" width="20px"></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: What error did the query throw?

Comment: Check your `DB` connections and `echo` `mysql_error()` function after `mysql_query()`.

Comment: check is query is executing or not `if(! $result) {
      die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   echo "Deleted data successfully\n";`

Comment: **Turn error reporting on**. Saves hours of debugging in the dark. In this case you'd see a "converting array to string" error because `$id = $_GET['id'];` but `name = "id[]"` i.e. id is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing `id` correctly on url.

NOTE: Please don't use **mysql_**, they are deprecated. Use **mysqli_** or **PDO**.

Change:

```
<td><a href="deletedisplaytype.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><img src="delete.jpg" width="20px"></a></td>
```

To:

```
<td><a href="deletedisplaytype.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><img src="delete.jpg" width="20px"></a></td>
```

Otherwise, code looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

every '`<td><input>`' you are are not closing input tag 
your td

```
<td><input type="text" name = "id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"</td>
```

after close

```
<td><input type="text" name = "id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"></td>
```